# Negate an NSDecimalNumber without losing the fractional part

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I'm using this code to invert an NSDecimalNumber for easier arithmetic:

```
    self.thisTransaction.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.amountField.text locale:NSLocale.currentLocale];

    NSLog(@"1 thisTransaction.amount is %@",self.thisTransaction.amount);

    // Inverts the transaction amount

    // This code negates the number, but chops off the part on the right side of the decimal

    self.thisTransaction.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[self.thisTransaction.amount longLongValue] exponent:0 isNegative:YES];

    NSLog(@"2 thisTransaction.amount is %@",self.thisTransaction.amount);
```

Well, I thought the arithmetic would be easier, anyway. However, as revealed in the console readout below, the code negates the number, but truncates the number at the decimal point and returns a whole integer instead of a decimal:

```
2015-05-27 10:07:30.767 XXXXX[11835:10266658] 1 thisTransaction.amount is 25.49
2015-05-27 10:07:39.735 XXXXX[11835:10266658] 2 thisTransaction.amount is -25
```

I've looked at quite a few posts on SO, but they seem to go around in circles. I'd sure appreciate some guidance.

**EDIT:**

Pursuant to @rmaddy's suggestion below, I changed the code as follows:

```
    self.thisTransaction.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.amountField.text locale:NSLocale.currentLocale];

    NSLog(@"1 thisTransaction.amount is %@",self.thisTransaction.amount);

    // Inverts the transaction amount

    NSDecimalNumber * invertedMultiplier = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"-1"];

    self.thisTransaction.amount = [self.thisTransaction.amount decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:invertedMultiplier];



    NSLog(@"2 thisTransaction.amount is %@",self.thisTransaction.amount);
```

This seems to work fine.

Comment: The accepted answer was amended after I made the edit. And in fact, i used a slightly different approach than the amended answer. Apparently both strategies will work, but the fix was clearly suggested by @rmaddy's original answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to negate an `NSDecimalNumber` you can simply do:

```
NSDecimalNumber *originalNumber = ... // the original decimal number

NSDecimalNumber *negatedNumber = [originalNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:-1]];
```

And for fun, here's another way:

```
NSDecimalNumber *anotherNegate = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberBySubtracting:originalNumber];
```

Comment: That almost worked, but I had to rephrase it as shown in the edit above. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. Fixed the use of the `-1`.

Comment: I stumbled over an alternate fix as shown above. But your's looks more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for another option. I have to admit that I'm having a hell of a time coming to grips with the multi-stepped two-way conversions needed to deal with accepting, manipulating, and displaying numbers stored in Core Data. I can use all the help I can get. Thanks again!